# Can you get two packets in one socket recv call for multicast?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, multicast

Self explanatory question. Can we get multiple UDP packets in one socket recv call when using Multicast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `recvfrom` or `recv` on a UDP socket, you will only ever receive one complete packet at a time.

This applies to both unicast and multicast packets.

Comment: Can you please indicate the source of this statement?

Comment: @multiplayer1080 [man udp](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html): *"All receive operations return only one packet"*,  It's the nature of being a datagram oriented protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The  recvmmsg() system call is an extension of recvmsg(2) that allows the caller to receive multiple messages from a socket using a single system call.
(This has performance benefits for some applications.)  A further extension over recvmsg(2) is support for a timeout on the receive operation.

Comment: This might be useful information, but it seems the question was about the `recv` call instead.